# How to turn off Includes in XSD during compilation ?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Is there a way of tell the `XmlSchemaSet` to ignore the includes during compilation ?

```
var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallback;
schemaSet.Add(targetNamespace, filepath);
schemaSet.Compile();
```

If i do not compile , that ignores the includes , but i don't get the `ElementSchemaType` property of the `XmlSchemaElement` , it remains null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would more interesting if you could also describe why you would want to ignore external references during compilation. Typically, these external references (either include or import) are needed since these would provide definitions for components that are actually referenced, such as a type, element, group, etc. One point of caution, in general, is that a redefine cannot be turned off (it'll fail immediately).

The closest you can ever get to your requirement is to define a custom resolver (extending from [XmlUrlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx)), that you associate with your reader via [XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx); "turning off" would translate in returning null in the overriding [GetEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.getentity.aspx) method.

If instead of "turning off" you may find you need a "redirect", then the above is definitely how you could it (instead a null you would return a stream to the schema you want).

One thing you have to keep in mind is that if the XmlSchemaSet needs that include/import you wish to turn off, it will never compile if it doesn't resolve. If it does not compile, then all the PSVI properties (ElementSchemaType being one of them) will not be populated. Which kind of goes back to why you would want such a thing?

Comment: I have realised over the course of the last 3 weeks,what would the turning off or on do. I realise i really need it to be ON. I wanted to turn off the includes and imports because i was iterating thorugh all the types in the schema and then converting them into JSONSchema. Now , i have managed to do that successfully. Initially the recursive nature of the schema would gave me a headache, the side effects still persist.I wanted all the possible information about the schema and then write it out to JSONSchema. Strange requirement i guess but it has indeed proved to be a thoughtful exercise.